# onkeypress event of textbox in ItemTemplate is not firing on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was trying to validate decimal number for 2 decimal point with onKeypress event of textbox.
it is working fine with IE. But not with chrome and firefox. But my page design and javascipt function given below.
could somebody help me to sort out this issue.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="grid-container-style">
                        <ig:WebDataGrid ID="grdname" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            TabIndex="5" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                            ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyFields="Id" EnableDataViewState="True"
                            DefaultColumnWidth="100%">
                            <AjaxIndicator Enabled="False" />
                            <Columns>
                                <ig:TemplateDataField Key="field" Width="8%">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJanuary" Width="100%" runat="server" TabIndex="5" ondblclick="this.focus();this.select()"
                                            MaxLength="12" onchange="ValueChange(event,this,'field')" onkeypress="javascript:return InputDecimalCheck(event,this);"
                                            SkinID="numeric-textbox" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(((Infragistics.Web.UI.TemplateContainer)Container).DataItem, "field") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <Header Text="field" />
                                    <Footer />
                                </ig:TemplateDataField>
                            </Columns>
                            <Behaviors>
                                <ig:Selection RowSelectType="None" CellClickAction="Cell" CellSelectType="None">
                                </ig:Selection>
                                <ig:Activation Enabled="true">
                                </ig:Activation>
                                <ig:RowSelectors Enabled="false" RowNumbering="true" />
                                <ig:ColumnMoving Enabled="false" />
                            </Behaviors>
                        </ig:WebDataGrid>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript code given below

```
function InputDecimalCheck(e, txtControl) {
    if ((e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 45) || e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46) {
        return false;
    }
    // . = 46
    var text = txtControl.value;

    // Only one decimal point
    if (e.which == 46 && text.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        return false;
    }
    var decimalIndex = text.length - text.indexOf('.');
    // Only 2 numbers after decimal
    if (text.indexOf('.') != -1 && (text.length - text.indexOf('.')) > 2 && !(txtControl.selectionStart <= text.indexOf('.'))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

chrome and firefox is not detecting its function call.

Comment: InputDecimalCheck or  txtBoxKeyPress??

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to suit to your requirement. I hope you can understand the logic.

You copy paste the following code and try from your side.

Write the following code in your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress", "return InputDecimalCheck(event,'"+ TextBox1.ClientID +"');");
}
```

Javascript code:

```
function InputDecimalCheck(key, txtControl) {
    var unicode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;

    if ((unicode == 45) || unicode != 8 && unicode != 0 && (unicode < 48 || unicode > 57) && unicode != 46) {
        return false;
    }
    // . = 46
    var text = document.getElementById(txtControl).value;

    // Only one decimal point
    if (unicode == 46 && text.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        return false;
    }
    var decimalIndex = text.length - text.indexOf('.');
    // Only 2 numbers after decimal
    if (text.indexOf('.') != -1 && (text.length - text.indexOf('.')) > 2 && !(txtControl.selectionStart <= text.indexOf('.'))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. your link was really useful. I found the actual problem. Keypress event is over writing in my master page for some other purpose. is there any other solution?

Comment: I couldn't understand your message. "Keypress event is over writing in my master page for some other purpose." - means? Show me some evidance so that I can work on that.